# Unable to remove User-Agent Header in API Connect call

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

my APIConnect API running on Bluemix is calling another API and I want to remove the User-Agent Header. I am using apim.setvariable in a Gatewayscript. Its working for some (e.g. Origin, Referer, ...) but not for the User-Agent. The User-Agent is still there.

```
apim.setvariable('message.headers.X-IBM-Client-Id', 'null','clear');
apim.setvariable('message.headers.X-IBM-Client-Secret', 'null', 'clear');
apim.setvariable('message.headers.Origin', 'null', 'clear');
apim.setvariable('message.headers.Referer', 'null', 'clear');
apim.setvariable('message.headers.X-Client-IP', 'null', 'clear');

apim.setvariable('request.headers.user-agent', 'null', 'clear');
apim.setvariable('request.headers.User-Agent', 'null', 'clear');
apim.setvariable('message.headers.user-agent', 'null', 'clear');
apim.setvariable('message.headers.User-Agent', 'null', 'clear');
```

How can I remove the User-Agent header?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using a Proxy node instead of an Invoke node after your gateway script.

Comment: Changed from Invoke to Proxy, but it does not solve the problem. User-Agent Header is still there.

Comment: What happens if you set it in a "set variable" policy?

Comment: still the same - User-Agent header is passed to the called API.